# Using forall in minizinc with an array set (not contiguous)

Tags: minizinc

I'm trying to use a forall instance to add a constraint but I got this error and I'm not sure which should I do.

> (array slice must be contiguous)
> in call 'forall'
> in array comprehension expression
> with i = {10,24}
> in binary '<=' operator expression
> in call 'slice_1d'

I am working in a schedulling problem, and I need to apply a restriction which determines that a set of tasks (determined by suc) can only starts after a specific task (determined by 1..nTasks) is already finished.

The model follows

```
include "globals.mzn";
int: n_res;
array [1..n_res] of int: res_cap;
int: n_tasks;
array [1..n_tasks] of int: duration;
array [1..n_res, 1..n_tasks] of int: res_req;
array [1..n_tasks] of set of int: suc;
int: t_max = sum(i in 1..n_tasks)(duration[i]);
array [1..n_tasks] of var 0..t_max: start;
array [1..n_tasks] of var 0..t_max: end;
var 0..t_max: makespan;

% constraint that I can't implement. this constraint should make every task[i] to start after a set of tasks{i} are finished. The set is defined by the array suc.

constraint forall (i in suc)(end[i] <= start[i]);

constraint cumulative(start, duration, row(res_req, 1), res_cap[1]);
constraint cumulative(start, duration, row(res_req, 2), res_cap[2]);
constraint cumulative(start, duration, row(res_req, 3), res_cap[3]);
constraint cumulative(start, duration, row(res_req, 4), res_cap[4]);

constraint forall(i in 1..n_tasks)(end[i] = start[i]+duration[i]);
constraint makespan = max(i in 1..n_tasks)(end[i]);

solve minimize makespan;
```

The arrays suc and 1..nTasks have the same number of lines.

I have a 1d array with the specific sets of tasks that can start after the task[i] is over.

In a smaller instance, for example:
suc = [{5, 15}, {17, 23, 28}, {10, 12}, {8}]

What i need to implement is:

> end[i] | i in 1..nTasks <= start[i] | i in suc

For the specific set that I posted, it could be done manually like this:

```
 end[1] <= start[5]
 end[1] <= start[15]
 end[2] <= start[17]
 end[2] <= start[23]
 end[2] <= start[28]
 end[3] <= start[10]
 end[3] <= start[12]
 end[4] <= start[8]
```

I just start using minizinc and something tells me that I'm missing something that may be simple, however, it's been a while and I can't implement it.

How can I write a forall instance that can do this?

Comment: It would help if you show the model that gives this error. Also, please include data (as small dataset as possible).

Comment: I added the model and the dataset for the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is this constraint (as the error indicates):

```
constraint forall (i in suc)(end[i] <= start[i]);
```

where you trying use `suc` as a generator for the loop. The problem is that you want two things for this constraint: the start of the current task should be before the successor of that task. And this is not possible using your approach since `i` will have value such as `{ 10, 24 }`, but there is no value (reference) of the current task (i.e. the value of `start[i]`).

Here is a way of solving this: Use `i in n_res` to loop through all the tasks (`i` is the i'th task), and then loop through `suc[i]` to get the successors of each task.

```
constraint forall (i in 1..n_res) (
    forall(s in suc[i]) (         
        end[i] <= start[s]
    )
);
```

Another way, which is perhaps simpler, is to combine the two `forall` loops into one loop:

```
constraint forall (i in 1..n_res, s in suc[i]) (
   end[i] <= start[s]
);
```

When I ran the model it generated this solution:

```
% obj = 51
start = array1d(1..30, [7, 21, 4, 31, 6, 41, 34, 3, 35, 39, 21, 28, 47, 0, 38, 48, 44, 35, 28, 7, 10, 34, 11, 47, 41, 3, 11, 3, 22, 17]);
end = array1d(1..30, [17, 25, 5, 34, 11, 51, 35, 7, 41, 47, 28, 35, 51, 3, 48, 51, 48, 38, 35, 12, 11, 44, 19, 48, 47, 7, 18, 9, 31, 21]);
makespan = 51;
----------
% obj = 51
==========
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I used the approach where you combined two forall loops into one loop and it worked perfectly.